# User Quota Default Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am sure I should either know this or have been able to determine this, but I am investigating an issue with user allocated space quotas and am wondering how to determine the default (if there is one).

Our users are running into a problem with a database set up by another individual and apparently none of them were set up with specific quotas.  Is there some default quota that users are set to and if so, how can I determine what that is or change it.  At this point, I am setting them individually, but was not sure why they were never established originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tablespace Quotas for a User](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/managing-security-for-oracle-database-users.html#GUID-62EEE321-01AF-4AF4-9210-A74476613A0A)

> ...
>
> By default, a user has no quota on any tablespace in the database.
>
> ...

Comment: Appreciated.  I have generally assigned a quota in the past.  Is it common to not assign any and what benefits are derived by doing that?

Comment: @FocusWiz Quotas should be used to control the amount of data a user can store in the database. The benefits of not assigning a quota are the same as not granting unnecessary privileges. However the most common reason I see for not assigning quotas is laziness/ignorance. Software vendors deliver their products with instructions in which they just simply grant the `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` system privilege to users, which renders tablespace quotas meaningless.